# Link not asking user to confirm

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink

I have this code

```
echo '<div class="bottomright"><a href="?id='
                . $topic_id
                . '&part=5"><img src="../assets/icons/Comments-    edit.png" /></a><a href="?id='
                . $topic_id
                . '&part=6"><img src="../assets/icons/Lock.png" /></a><a href="#" onclick="return confirm("Are you sure?")"><img src="../assets/icons/Trash.png" /></a></div>';
```

When I click Trash.png it is supposed to ask "Are you sure"? But it doesn't...

Am I missing something here?

Comment: _“Am I missing something here?”_ – yes: That the first `"` is the starting delimiter of the onclick attribute value, and the second is the closing one.

Comment: onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

`onclick="return confirm("Are you sure?")"`

Note the quote ambiguity. You have to change the quote symbols somehow to pair properly, probably by escaping a set of single quotes. Both of the following work:

`onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')"`

`onclick=\'return confirm("Are you sure?")\'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')">
```

You have to escape single quotes.

Because:

- `onclick="return confirm("Are you sure?")"` is not `JavaScript`
  valid. (notice `"` conflict)
- `onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"` would not be `PHP`
  valid (notice `'` conflict because the whole echo function is wrapped inside single quotes)

Another option, would be to do this:

`'<a href="#" onclick="return confirm('. "'Are you sure?'" .')">'`

Which actually closes the `echo` quotes, concatenates the `'Are you sure?'` and concatantes the rest.